# VS Code - The term 'git' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have new PC and now installed latest version of Visual Studio Code.

Launched newly installed VS Code and opened terminal in VS Code.

In terminal entered Git command and got error:

git : The term 'git' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.

I don't have separate Git installation and don't want to install it as have VS Code already installed and **Source Control section works fine in VS Code** so means Git should be somehow integrated in VS Code, so my question:

How can I use Git via VS Code terminal without additionally installing separate Git software considering that I can use git functionality via GUI in VS Code?

Comment: Check the VS Code git configuration it might say where the git binary it uses is actually located so you could add it to the path.

Comment: If you want to use the git command line on windows, I would really recommend installing git directly. It ships with the *git bash*-utitlity, a WinTerm profile for git, and some windows-related git configuration steps, like enabling symlink support.

Comment: Even though vscode has git support that does not conclusively imply that the git command line binary is used. The most likely scenario is that they use a library like [libgit2](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2), although sometimes [editors use the git binary](https://github.blog/2017-05-16-integrating-git-in-atom/).

Comment: Information on the internet about how VS Code integrates with git seems to indicate that it uses a git binary. The [FAQ](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/sourcecontrol/faq#_i-have-github-desktop-installed-on-my-computer-but-vs-code-ignores-it) seems to say that much. The question it would be nice if someone can confirm if that's the case

Comment: Is there a reason for you not wanting to install git separately? you are heading for a unique setup where nobody will be able to help you if your setup breaks because you are doing some weird unexpected homebrew "fun"...

Comment: I thought git is simply integrated in one of vs code folders and I could avoid installing git separately, but if it use git binary that more complicated, so the easiest option most likely would be just installing git separately, thanks for help guys

Answer (score 1):

You can download and install git from the official website:

https://git-scm.com/download/win